# What does it mean when written id=-1 in django request?

Tags: python, django

I'm reading someone's code, and there is written

```
get_object_or_404(Order, id=-1)
```

Could someone explain the purpose of `id=-1`?

Comment: It aims to fetch an `Order` object with `id=-1`, and if that fails, it will raise a 404 error. Since in most databases, integers are (strictly) positive, this will probably *always* fail

Comment: found out, it was a predefined item, like a template...need to load from fixtures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well [**`get_object_or_404`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) takes as input a model or queryset, and aims to filter it with the remaining *positional* and *named* parameters. It then aims to fetch that object, and raises a 404 in case the object does *not* exists.

Here we thus aim to obtain an `Order` object with `id=-1`. So the query that is executed "behind the curtains" is:

```
Order.objects.get(id=-1)  # SELECT order.* FROM order WHERE id=-1
```

In most databases `id`s are however (strictly) positive (if these are assigned automatically). So *unless* an `Order` object is *explicitly* saved with `id=-1`, this will always raise a 404 exception.

Sometimes however one stores objects with negative id to make it easy to retrieve and update "special" ones (although personally I think it is not a good practice, since this actually is related to the *singleton* and *global state* anti-patterns). You thus can look (for example in the database, or in the code) if there are objects with negative `id`s. If these objects are not created, then this code will *always* result in a 404 response.

Comment: found out, it was a predefined item, like a template...need to load from fixtures.

Comment: @petriichuk: yes, that was the hypothesis I have put forward in the last paragraph :)